# How do you display framerate in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I would ideally like to know a console command that will display the framerate (current and a running averages would be even better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TDT` worked in Oblivion engine but is not supported anymore by `Fallout 3`/`Fallout New Vegas` engine.

Unfortunately, at the moment, there isn't any known console commands that can show FPS in-game.

You have to use 3rd-parties software, like [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/download.php), RivaTuner overlay, etc.

I normally use Fraps trial version, that allows to show/hide the FPS in almost all games I tried.

Comment: It seems that Fraps, or tools like it is the way to go.